# Getting base station name using J2ME

Tags: java-me

How can get the base station name using J2ME?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way generally for vanilla J2ME/MIDP.  Specific platforms though may provide some way.  For example, with BlackBerry you can use `net.rim.device.api.system.GPRSInfo` and related classes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly it's not a standard implementation and it changes from a manufacturer to another. however you can try this code:

```
String cellID = System.getProperty("com.sonyericsson.net.cellid");  
if (cellID == null)
     cellID = System.getProperty("CellID");
```

It works on most SonyEricsson phones and Motorola. If you have luck, with other brands.